# get pointer for CallInst?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang, llvm-clang

I'm working on a LLVM pass where I'm interested in calls on function pointers. Besides from knowing what the pointer actually points too (or what will actually be called) I would like to have the function pointer itself.

So from `CallInst::getCalledValue()` I can get the function that will be called, I want the function pointer that was actually used.

In this example, I would like to get `ptr1` (address, variable object itself, name, something):

```
int main() {
    int (*ptr1)(int) = &f1;
    ptr1(42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess I should add that I'm expecting I will need to do this before I am at the IR level. With a RecursiveASTConsumer I can easy see this, but I don't have any means to save this information.

Answer (score 0):

Then you aren't working on a pass and should just modify clang to get you calls through function pointers and put out the information somewhere.

Comment: Well at one point there was a AnnotationManager that worked, something similar would probably help me. If I could somehow mark that in the AST and have it still exist for the Pass to look for it seems like I could do this easily.